# Scout not working even though Java Runtime is installed on Mac

Tags: macos, sass, compass

Today my Compass/Sass stopped compiling and i was unable to get it working again. So i installed Scout. But Scout wouldn’t run until i installed Java Runtime for Mac. So I downloaded and installed Java Runtime for Mac. But when running Scout I am still prompted as if Java Runtime was never installed. I see the Java Runtime in my System Preferences so I assume it’s working?

I’m running Mac OS 10.10.1 Yosemite

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. You need to run a legacy version of Java for some applications to still work. Here's the download link and info from Apple:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

> Java for OS X 2015-001 installs the legacy Java 6 runtime for OS X
>   10.11 El Capitan, OS X 10.10 Yosemite, OS X 10.9 Mavericks, OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, and OS X 10.7 Lion.
>
> This package is exclusively intended for support of legacy software
>   and installs the same deprecated version of Java 6 included in the
>   2014-001 and 2013-005 releases.
>
> Quit any Java applications before installing this update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Scout but you might need the older JNI (Java Native Interface) version of Java (1.6) that Apple deprecated a long time ago but is still available if you know now to find it.

The easiest way to install it is to use this command in Terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home --task JNI --request
```

and follow the prompts (it will pop up a dialog box offering to install the requested version).  OS X can host multiple versions of Java a once so installing this older version shouldn't affect your existing installation.